# Why is my Windows Forms application changing size across computers?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I've been developing a Windows Forms application with a Windows Media Player COM embedded into it. Normally, it looks like this:
[image]

Today, I opened the program on my laptop, and got this instead:
[image]

Why are some of the elements of my program resizing when run on a different computer? How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show the properties for WMP object?

Comment: @StefanE [Here ya go](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bS6YM.png)

Comment: Try setting maximum and minimum size so that they both are the same as size

Comment: Doesn't look like the typical cause, a different video DPI setting.  Looks like the Font property of the form changed.

Comment: I would put the control in a Panel and then set dock to Fill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchoring is what is causing the media control to mis-shape itself. You currently have the control anchored to Top|Right.

What you need to do is drop the Anchor settings on the media control - put the control in a panel and set the DockType to Fill; then Anchor the panel - Left | Top.

Answer (score 2):

Try to dock controls on form to ensure that the controls position will stay normal in all situations
have look to this
[DockStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dockstyle.aspx)

Comment: I cannot use Dock, because I'm using Anchors to resize the Control when the rest of the form resizes, and the two are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @RavenDreamer: Anchoring is what is causing the media control to mis-shape itself. I think you have the control anchored to Top|Right. Drop the Anchor on the media control - put the control in a panel. Anchor the panel - Left | Top ; dock the control - Fill.

Comment: @IAbstract that's what I wound up doing, and it worked. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.